# Galaxy S7 OSX High Sierra tethering

Tags: android, hotspot, macos-highsierra

Before upgrading to High Sierra, wifi tethering was working great for me. Now it doesn't. Short of going back to earlier versions of OSX, do I have any options?

Comment: Do you think that nobody is able to use WiFi tethering with High Sierra? If not, you need to explain what makes your system different.

Comment: I got that impression initially,but now think it could be user error. I would like to better understand how hotspots work.

Comment: So sorry Internet. I really did spend hours the other day, trying to get a connection, but now tethering is "just working". Posting this in case anybody else runs across it. Not sure if I fixed anything. The only silghtly unusual thing I did, while trying to fix, was to logout, and login as another user. It was shortly after that that things seemed to start working. Not saying that did it but ...